# agg function returning a wrong result in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregation

Here is my pandas dataframe:

`print(df.loc[df['prodID'] == 'HLY'])`
[image]

I want to find out the min and max and average, but for min and max it is giving me wrong result:

`print(df.loc[df['prodID'] == 'HLY'].agg({'price':['min','max']}))`
[image]

as you can see, the min is 9.99 and max is 56.00

what's wrong here and how do I fix?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is your column type is `object` not numeric

```
df.price=pd.to_numeric(df.price)

df.loc[df['prodID'] == 'HLY'].agg({'price':['min','max']})
```